# Object literal expression using this. to access the context of the code's value

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm going through a course and working through the example on object literal expressions, the example code given

```
'use strict';
var price = 5.99, quantity = 10;
var prod = { price: 7, quantity: 1, 
    calc() {
        return this.price * this.quantity
    }
};
console.log(prod.calc());
```

says that when run, the console should have 59.90 in it as "this" is referring to the context of the code, not the object that contains the function.   When I run the code (using the latest Chrome) the console shows 7.    If I remove the two "this."

```
return price * quantity
```

it returns 59.90 which is the opposite of what the video says it should be doing.   Any idea where I'm going wrong with this?
Thanks

Comment: Either the video is wrong, or you misunderstood it. We can't solve that here.

Comment: *"says that when run, the console should have 59.90 in it as "this" is referring to the context of the code, not the object that contains the function."* That's incorrect. *"Any idea where I'm going wrong with this?"* You aren't, if that's really what the video said.. I suggest finding a different resource, as apparently the one you're using isn't as reliable as one would like. :-)

Comment: Note that this type of literal is a very recent feature of JavaScript. It's possible that a tutorial was badly updated.

Comment: I voted for closing as off-topic, because we can't solve that here. I don't find this linked QA useful.

Comment: It's plural sight which have a good reputation (especially as work are paying for it :)